# A function to determine whether one type extends or inherits another in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Is there a way in PHP to know if one class inherits another?

```
class Controller
{
}

class HomeController extends Controller
{
}

class Dummy
{
}

// What I would like to do

    $result = class_extends('HomeController', 'Controller'); /// true
    $result = class_extends('Dummy', 'Controller'); /// false
```

Comment: @ChristopheD you have the right idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [instanceof](https://www.php.net/instanceof).

Note that `implements` is incorrect.  `instanceof` should be used in both cases (checking whether an object is an inherited class, or whether the object implements an interface).

Example from manual:

```
<?php
interface MyInterface
{
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface
{
}

$a = new MyClass;

var_dump($a instanceof MyClass);
var_dump($a instanceof MyInterface);
?>
```

gives:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. I don't know what I was thinking. Late night here ;)

Comment: Ha ha... I was going to comment, but by the time I hit submit on my own, you had already fixed it.  :D

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use

```
if ($foo instanceof ClassName)
    // do stuff...
```

**EDIT**: As far as I know, this should even work for interfaces...

Comment: Forget the implements stuff. I was losing it ;)

Comment: is there a way to not construct the object?

Comment: Yes, you can use `class_parents()` for that: http://de2.php.net/manual/de/function.class-parents.php

Comment: Same thing for interfaces: `class_implements()` - http://php.net/manual/function.class-implements.php

Answer (score 1):

May I recomment the [`instanceof` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php)?

```
class A { }
class B extends A { }
class C { }

$b = new B;
$c = new C;

var_dump($b instanceof A, $c instanceof A) // bool(true), bool(false)
```