# [PHP]How to check if a class inherits another class without instantiating it?

Tags: php, class, types

I have some class name.
How to check if a class inherits another class without instantiating it?

```
 if (!class_exists($controller)) //AND I have check type
        {

            $objectController = new IndexController();
            $objectController->index();
        }
```

Comment: Have you looked at something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836782/a-function-to-determine-whether-one-type-extends-or-inherits-another-in-php

Comment: The Fine Manual not useful enough? http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php

Comment: I need checking type WITHOUT creating object.

Comment: @jprofitt: have you even try to read this question before finding for duplicates?

Comment: @zerkms Blast from the past question. I do remember this one, however, and realizing that it was the wrong language immediately after I voted to close. Wasn't much I could do at the time since you can't undo your vote. I will vote (I'm assuming with you) to reopen however.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll have to use reflection for that, it's pretty large topic:

http://ca.php.net/manual/fr/book.reflection.php

Look at the doc a little, try something and if you still have questions, something more precise, then post another question on that topic.

Comment: Voting donw, not because its wrogn answer, but because there are much better ones.

Comment: If the answer is not bad at all, you shouldn't downvote it, you should just not upvote it and upvote the good ones... You are making me lose points because the author chose the wrong answer and thus punishing me for nothing... just my two cents

Comment: Actually the problem is in stackoverflow. The answer on the top of the list should be the one with most upvotes. I came here to find a simple answer and as usual I look the answer that's chosen. But what I actually need is is_subclass_of - it's simple, fast and does the job.

Answer (score 29):

You can use `is_subclass_of`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php

```
class TestA {}
class TestB extends TestA {}
class TestC extends TestB {}

var_dump(is_subclass_of('TestA', 'TestA')); // false
var_dump(is_subclass_of('TestB', 'TestA')); // true
var_dump(is_subclass_of('TestC', 'TestA')); // true
```

Comment: It worths noting that  is_subclass_of calls autoloader in case the classname does not exist. It doesn't if the third parameter is FALSE, but then you can't provide a string as first parameter.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, though it ranks high on Google right now and brought me here while looking for an alternative to reflection. After not finding any, I decided to post a working example for all here.

You can do this by using reflection. Try not to rely on reflection too much since it can be resource-intensive.

```
class TestA {}
class TestB extends TestA {}
class TestC extends TestA {}

$reflector = new ReflectionClass('TestA');
$result    = $reflector->isSubclassOf('TestA');
var_dump($result); // false

$reflector = new ReflectionClass('TestB');
$result    = $reflector->isSubclassOf('TestA');
var_dump($result); // true

$reflector = new ReflectionClass('TestC');
$result    = $reflector->isSubclassOf('TestA');
var_dump($result); // false
```

For more info on class reflection, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

For more info on reflection in general, see http://php.net/reflection

Comment: The last results returns "true", not "false" as TestC extends TestA. Also, if TestD extends TestB, the (new ReflectionClass('TestD'))->isSubclassOf('TestA'); should return "true"